# module 'scipy.stats._continuous_distns' has no attribute 'frechet_r_gen'

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

When

```
import lmoments3 as lm
from lmoments3 import distr
```

I get `module 'scipy.stats._continuous_distns' has no attribute 'frechet_r_gen'`
I `cd`ed into scipy/stats folder, and there is no presence of 'frechet_r_gen'

I have tried `pip install update scipy lmoments3` and `pip install --user scipy`

I am using conda environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.6.0.html

This distribution was removed in scipy 1.6.0. So either install scipy 1.5.4 or make this `lmoments3` module update to a more recent scipy version.

Comment: Thank you, solved with ` pip install scipy==1.4.1` with lmoments3==1.0.1